# Can I still use old wallets after pruning?

Tags: wallet, pruning

I want to move my node to a laptop with less than 70gb free space. Would pruning make wallets older than pruned blocks unusable? If that is not an issue,  what files should I copy to my new node in order to keep using my wallets?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it until we get a solid answer to issues like this https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/121849/loading-wallet-produces-last-wallet-synchronisation-goes-beyond-pruned-data-af

Answer (score 0):

Once the wallet has already scanned a range of blocks, you can safely prune these blocks. However you won't be able to re-scan this block range in the future.

Copying your wallet file over to your fresh node should be fine as long as the wallet's tip (the latest height at which it was synced, ie opened on the old node) is superior to the last pruned height on the new node.

Comment: Copying the wallet folder to the pruned node resulted in an error and bitcoind shutting down `Error: Prune: last wallet synchronisation goes beyond pruned data. You need to -reindex (download the whole blockchain again in case of pruned node)` although the wallet was working just fine on the full node

Comment: Well that's exactly what i said.. The new node needs not to have pruned the blocks the wallet hasn't yet processed. Process those blocks on the old node and then copy it over.

Comment: That is what I did. The old node has already processed those blocks. -getinfo gives the correct balance on the old node. Still got that error after copying the wallet over:(

Comment: "Process those blocks on the old node and then copy it over." What does this mean exactly @AntoinePoinsot?